# Git barebones repo

Tags: git, dropbox

Can some one please explain what a barebones repo is? And how I can setup one in my dropbox to store to? There are other questions mentioning to do this, but I can't seem to get a clear explanation of a what a barebones repo is, where to set it up (except for the recommendation of in your dropbox to allow for backup - which is a good idea and why I'm asking) and how to integrate it into my workflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably thinking of a "bare" repo, which is a Git repo without an attached working directory. You can create one using `git --bare init` or `git clone --bare`.

Since it doesn't have a working directory, you can't edit files with it, but you can push into and pull from it.